# Excel VBA Macro to search a column and display rows in pop up message based on column value

Tags: vba, excel

Im looking for some help creating an Excel macro that will seach Column A for cells that are not blank and column B for blanks on the same row then display a pop up message box when the workbook is opened showing the information for the rows that contain a name in Column A but do not have any information in the column B to remind people to complete items on the sheet.

Is this possible at all? IF so can someone please help with the code to make this work.

Many Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Are you able to help with the VBA code i would need to use?

Comment: Yes - what have you tried so far?

Comment: Im a bit of a novice when it comes to VBA, so dont even know where to start with this kind of coding. Ive only done basic with macro buttons to show and hide sheets from view and macro password boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've told me, this is what I can provide. Running it will find the first occurrence where Column A is not blank and Column B is missing text. You can then have your user fill it in, run it again to check for more.

```
Sub checkcolumns()
Dim i As Long

'100 is the last row you want to check. Change accordingly

For i = 1 To 100       
    'Change Sheet1 to your worksheet name
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Row " & i & " is missing a value in column B!", vbExclamation, "Missing value!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i

MsgBox "Search complete, all values are in place!", vbInformation, "Success!"
End Sub
```

To display all in one message:

```
Sub checkcolumns()
Dim i As Long
Dim message As String

For i = 1 To 100
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
        message = message + "Row " & i & " is missing a value in Column B! "
    End If
Next i

MsgBox message, vbInformation, "Success!"
End Sub
```

Comment: That’s great thank you!

Is there anyway to have it display in the pop up box all the rows that have the missing information?

As at the moment it pops up with the message:
 Row 2 is missing a value in column B!
Then stops even if there are others with missing information below it.

Is there anyway to have it pop up with all the information in one box something like:

Row 2 is missing a value in Column B!
Row 5 is missing a value in Column B!
Row 6 is missing a value in Column B!
Row 8 is missing a value in Column B!
Row 10 is missing a value in Column B!

Comment: Well how many rows are you working with? With this first version you could run it, then fill in the blank, run it again and it will find the next occurrence. The issue is that the message box can only hold so much text. If finds 20 occurrences where Column B is missing text, it might be too much to put in the message box.

Comment: I have edited my answer with another solution to display all the values in one message box.